# How to compute the square root of a number in ATS?

Tags: ats

I know that one can use the sqrt function in libc/math for doing it:

```
staload
Math =
"libats/libc/SATS/math.sats"

val sqrt2 = $Math.sqrt(2.0)
val sqrt3 = $Math.sqrt(3.0)
```

I am looking for a direct implementation of sqrt in ATS if possible.

Answer (score 1):

See [this snippet](https://glot.io/snippets/ekjoyrj10z) for a basic implementation of the square root using the [Newton-Raphson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method).